# PHP, how to get datepicker value from database if date != current date

Tags: javascript, php, datepicker

I spend more than two days with no luck, when open site, its display all orders for current date. But sometimes I need to add order in previous date, after inserting, query return me to the index page and again its display the orders today, but i want now to display the last record which have different date.

**code in index page:**

```
<script>
$('#datepicker').change(function () {    

$.post('check_data.php', {    
    dtpickerdate : $(this).val()
}, function (response) {    

    $('table').html(response);
  });
 });

 $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",}).datepicker("setDate", new Date()).change();
</script>
```

**insert query:**

```
$conn->query("INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES('$order_no','$address','$no_ofppl','$d_time','$k_time','$date',now(),'$done','$mile')") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));          
    echo '
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            alert("Saved Record");
            window.location = "index.php";
            </script>
    ';       }
 }else
  {
echo 'Result Error';
   }
```

**Check_data.php**

```
        <thead class = "alert-info">
 <tr>
                <th>Kitchen Time</th>

                <th>Order#</th>

                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Driver#</th>
                <th>Delivery Time</th>
                <th># of People</th>
                <th>Miles</th>
            </tr> </thead><tbody>
  <?php
$dtpickerdate = isset($_POST['dtpickerdate']) ? $_POST['dtpickerdate'] : NULL;

 $q_customer = $conn->query
                             ("SELECT * from orders inner JOIN customer_order on customer_order.order_no =orders.order_no and orders.date like'$dtpickerdate' inner join driver_order  on driver_order.order_no=orders.order_no LEFT JOIN customer on customer.phone=customer_order.phone order by k_time,time desc" )
 or die(mysqli_error());

 $k_time = '';
 while($f_customer = $q_customer->fetch_array()){
 $s=mysqli_num_rows($q_customer);
 ?>
  <tr>
 <?php   

    if($k_time == '' || $k_time != $f_customer['k_time']){
     $k_time = $f_customer['k_time'];
     echo '<td align="center" > <span style=" font-weight:bold;">' 
     .$f_customer['k_time']. '</td>';
      } else{
      echo "<td td style=' border: none;'>&nbsp;</td>";
      }
       echo "<td style='background-color: #5f5d5d; ' align='center'  span style='font-weight:bold;'> <a   href = '#' style='color:#ececec;font-weight:bold;' data-toggle = 'modal' data-target = '#action'>".$f_customer['order_no']."</a></td>";

   echo    "<td style='background-color: #5f5d5d;color:#ececec;'>" .$f_customer['first_name']."</td>"; 
  echo "<td style='background-color: #5f5d5d;color:#ececec;'>". $f_customer['last_name']."</td>";
   echo "<td style='background-color: #5f5d5d;color:#ececec;'>". $f_customer['address']."</td>";
   echo "<td style='background-color: #5f5d5d;color:#ececec;'>". $f_customer['driver_no']."</td>";
   echo "<td style='background-color: #5f5d5d;color:#ececec;'>".   $f_customer['d_time']."</td>";
   echo "<td style='background-color: #5f5d5d;color:#ececec;'>". $f_customer['no_ofppl']."</td>";
}
```

Comment: where is `check_data.php`? you should use a `SELECT ...` query in that script to query the db based on the date you selected in the date picker. Also you should use 'prepared statements' to insert the data, as the way you have it now is unsafe.

Comment: Edited: check_data.php, now please help me how to view data in both way: if open site display the orders which have the current date, but if ia added new order with previous date, then return to index.php and display orders with that previous date